# Gettimeofday not working when assigned to variable

Tags: c, printf, variable-assignment, gettimeofday

I have a simple timestamp issue. I am trying to get a timestamp using `gettimeofday` and it all works as it should when I print the value to the terminal however when I assign it to a variable it does not. I can not figure out what im doing wrong. The code and output looks as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    struct timeval t_struct;
    while(1){
        gettimeofday(&t_struct, NULL);
        printf("Print only: %f \n", (float) t_struct.tv_sec + (float) t_struct.tv_usec/1000000);
        float timestamp = (float) t_struct.tv_sec + (float) t_struct.tv_usec/1000000;
        printf("Assigned  : %f \n", timestamp);
        Sleep(100);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Print only: 1598259371.284617 
Assigned  : 1598259328.000000 
Print only: 1598259371.385117 
Assigned  : 1598259328.000000 
Print only: 1598259371.485873 
Assigned  : 1598259328.000000
```

Note that I am used to programming in Python and not C, I am aware that the issue might be trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to change the variable type to `double` instead of `float` and I also changed the division to be `/1000000.0` to avoid integer division.